# Draw on canvas on part of screen

Tags: java, android, canvas, draw

I want draw on canvas some picture, line, ring etc. but i want make this only on small area, on part screen. I have this layout "activity_main"

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<com.example.canavstest.Draw2d
    android:id="@+id/game"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />
```

and main class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
```

and class where i painting

```
public class Draw2d extends View{

public Draw2d(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    canvas.drawPaint(paint);
}
}
```

when i try to start my application i get next error

```
09-25 21:06:43.925: E/AndroidRuntime(28370): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.canavstest/com.example.canavstest.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class com.example.canavstest.Draw2d
```

what i doing wrong?

Comment: did you initialized your `Draw2d` in your `activity` ?

Comment: no, this all code in application. where i must initialize `Draw2d`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you spelt your packageName incorrectly. Check your AndroidManifest.

`com.example.canavstest.Draw2d`

Should probably be

`com.example.canvastest.Draw2d`

Notice the spelling of `canvas`

Edit: Also, you have not implemented the constructor that the LayoutInflater calls. Add this.

```
public Draw2d(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context, attrs);
}
```

Comment: No, i see my mistakes on title ))), but no, i copy this packageName and put in code

Comment: OK, yes. i Corrected my code like on your answer. and my application started work, thank you

Comment: Thank you. This solved a big issue in my Project. I was not using AttributeSet in my constructor.